# Unauthorized exception When Zuul Gateway Started through Eureka Server

Tags: spring-security, spring-security-oauth2, netflix-eureka, netflix-zuul, spring-cloud-security

I am working on Spring Boot migration from 1.5.12 to 2.1.14. We have to migrate Spring Cloud dependncies as well. So for this I have changed Spring cloud version
as 'Greenwich.SR4'(supported version for Spring Boot 2.1.x) from 'Dalston.SR4'.

```
//implementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security')
implementation('org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-security')
implementation('org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-oauth2')
//compile('org.springframework.security.oauth.boot:spring-security-oauth2-autoconfigure')
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
compile("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-server")
compile("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client")
compile("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-netflix-zuul")
```

I have Eureka Server and Zuul GateWay Application which is one of the micro service which will be acting as Proxy and eureka client shown below

```
Eureka Server:
----------------

 @SpringBootApplication(exclude = {
        HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class,
        JndiConnectionFactoryAutoConfiguration.class,
        DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class,
        DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration.class,
        SecurityAutoConfiguration.class
})
@EnableEurekaServer
@ComponentScan("com.swp.service.eureka")
public class EurekaRegistryApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication springApplication = new SpringApplication(EurekaApplication.class);
        springApplication.run(args);
    }
 
 application-eureka.properties:
 -----------------------------
 spring.application.name=eureka
server.port=8761
eureka.instance.hostname=localhost
eureka.client.registerWithEureka=false
eureka.client.fetchRegistry=false
eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=http://${eureka.instance.hostname}:${server.port}/eureka/
security.enabled=false
 
Zuul Gateway:
--------------- 
 @SpringBootApplication(exclude = {
        HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class,
        JndiConnectionFactoryAutoConfiguration.class,
        DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class,
        DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration.class,
        SecurityAutoConfiguration.class
})
@EnableZuulProxy
@EnableDiscoveryClient
@ComponentScan("com.swp.swp.service.zuul")
public class SWPGatewayApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {  
        SpringApplication springApplication = new SpringApplication(SWPGatewayApplication.class);
        springApplication.run(args);
    }
}

application-gateway.properties
-------------------------------

spring.application.name=zuul
server.port=8092
server.servlet.context-path=/swp-gateway
allowedOriginHeaders=http://localhost:9090
zuul.add-host-header=true
zuul.sensitiveHeaders=Cookie,Set-Cookie
zuul.host.connect-timeout-millis=300000
zuul.host.socket-timeout-millis=300000
zuul.routes.swp.path=/swpapp/**
zuul.routes.oauth.path=/authservice/**
zuul.routes.swp.serviceId=swpapp
zuul.routes.oauth.serviceId=oauthservice
ribbon.ReadTimeout=300000
ribbon.ConnectTimeout=300000
ribbon.eureka.enabled=true
hystrix.command.default.execution.isolation.thread.timeoutInMilliseconds=300000
eureka.client.registerWithEureka=false
eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=http://localhost:8761/eureka/
security.enabled=false
```

We have integrated spring security with Oauth2 and have Authorization server and Resource server like below.

```
Authorization server:
---------------------

@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
@ConditionalOnProperty(name="EnableJwtToken", matchIfMissing=true, havingValue="false")
public class AuthServerConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter implements AuthorizationServerConfigurer {
   
   
    @Bean
    public  AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return  super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;
    
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer oauthServer) throws Exception {
        logger.info("AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer", "Enter into AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer");
        oauthServer.checkTokenAccess("isAuthenticated()").checkTokenAccess("permitAll()");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/**").permitAll();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/**");
    
    etc.. config for in memory auth and token generation.
}


Resource Server:
------------------

@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
@EnableWebSecurity
@ConditionalOnProperty(name="EnableJWTSecurity", havingValue="false",matchIfMissing=true)
public class ResourceServerConfig extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {
    
    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        logger.info("ResourceServerConfig","Inside HttpSecurity http configure");
        /*http
                .authorizeRequests().
                antMatchers("/swp/**").
                authenticated()
                .anyRequest().permitAll();*/
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/**")
                .permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/**")
                .authenticated();
    }
}
```

I hava few other micro services as well along with these MS. When I start EurekaRegistry app which is Eureka server we have no erros and able to start them successfully.
but We have problem in running Zull Gateway Micro service which is giving the below error asking for authorization.

```
25408     SWP  DEBUG  zuul   org.apache.http.headers    << Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
25408     SWP  DEBUG  zuul   org.apache.http.headers    << Pragma: no-cache
25408     SWP  DEBUG  zuul   org.apache.http.headers  2020-07-10 02:37:22.909  << Expires: 0
25408     SWP  DEBUG  zuul   org.apache.http.headers  2020-07-10 02:37:22.909  << X-Frame-Options: DENY
25408     SWP  DEBUG  zuul   org.apache.http.headers  2020-07-10 02:37:22.909  << Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
25408     SWP  DEBUG  zuul   org.apache.http.headers  2020-07-10 02:37:22.909  << Transfer-Encoding: chunked
25408     SWP  DEBUG  zuul   org.apache.http.headers  2020-07-10 02:37:22.909  << Date: Fri, 10 Jul 2020 06:37:22 GMT
25408     SWP  DEBUG  zuul   org.apache.http.headers  2020-07-10 02:37:22.909  << Keep-Alive: timeout=60
25408     SWP  DEBUG  zuul   org.apache.http.headers  2020-07-10 02:37:22.909  << Connection: keep-alive
25408     SWP  DEBUG  zuul   o.a.h.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient  2020-07-10 02:37:22.909  Connection can be kept alive for 60000 MILLISECONDS
25408     SWP  DEBUG  zuul   o.a.h.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient  2020-07-10 02:37:22.909  Authentication required
25408     SWP  DEBUG  zuul   o.a.h.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient  2020-07-10 02:37:22.909  localhost:8761 requested authentication
25408     SWP  DEBUG  zuul   o.a.h.i.c.TargetAuthenticationStrategy  2020-07-10 02:37:22.909  Authentication schemes in the order of preference: [Negotiate, Kerberos, NTLM, CredSSP, Digest, Basic]
25408     SWP  DEBUG  zuul   o.a.h.i.c.TargetAuthenticationStrategy  2020-07-10 02:37:22.912  Challenge for Negotiate authentication scheme not available
25408     SWP  DEBUG  zuul   o.a.h.i.c.TargetAuthenticationStrategy  2020-07-10 02:37:22.912  Challenge for Kerberos authentication scheme not available
25408     SWP  DEBUG  zuul   o.a.h.i.c.TargetAuthenticationStrategy  2020-07-10 02:37:22.912  Challenge for NTLM authentication scheme not available
25408     SWP  DEBUG  zuul   o.a.h.i.c.TargetAuthenticationStrategy  2020-07-10 02:37:22.912  Challenge for CredSSP authentication scheme not available
25408     SWP  DEBUG  zuul   o.a.h.i.c.TargetAuthenticationStrategy  2020-07-10 02:37:22.912  Challenge for Digest authentication scheme not available
25408     SWP  DEBUG  zuul   org.apache.http.wire  2020-07-10 02:37:22.912   << "80[\r][\n]"
25408     SWP  DEBUG  zuul   org.apache.http.wire  2020-07-10 02:37:22.912   << **"{"timestamp":"2020-07-10T06:37:22.908+0000","status":401,
"error":"Unauthorized","message":"Unauthorized","path":"/eureka/apps/"}"**
25408     SWP  DEBUG  zuul   c.n.d.s.t.j.AbstractJerseyEurekaHttpClient  2020-07-10 02:37:22.912  Jersey HTTP GET http://localhost:8761/eureka//apps/?; statusCode=401
25408     SWP  DEBUG  zuul   org.apache.http.wire  2020-07-10 02:37:22.912   << "[\r][\n]"
25408     SWP  DEBUG  zuul   org.apache.http.wire  2020-07-10 02:37:22.912   << "0[\r][\n]"
25408     SWP  DEBUG  zuul   org.apache.http.wire  2020-07-10 02:37:22.912   << "[\r][\n]"
25408     SWP  DEBUG  zuul   c.n.d.s.MonitoredConnectionManager  2020-07-10 02:37:22.912  Released connection is reusable.
25408     SWP  DEBUG  zuul   c.n.d.shared.NamedConnectionPool  2020-07-10 02:37:22.912  Releasing connection [{}->http://localhost:8761][null]
25408     SWP  DEBUG  zuul   c.n.d.shared.NamedConnectionPool  2020-07-10 02:37:22.912  Pooling connection [{}->http://localhost:8761][null]; keep alive for 60000 MILLISECONDS
25408     SWP  DEBUG  zuul   c.n.d.shared.NamedConnectionPool  2020-07-10 02:37:22.912  Notifying no-one, there are no waiting threads
25408     SWP  DEBUG  zuul   c.n.d.s.t.d.RedirectingEurekaHttpClient  2020-07-10 02:37:22.912  Pinning to endpoint null
25408     SWP   WARN  zuul   c.n.d.s.t.d.RetryableEurekaHttpClient  2020-07-10 02:37:22.912  Request execution failure with status code 401; retrying on another server if available
25408     SWP  ERROR  zuul   c.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient  2020-07-10 02:37:22.912  DiscoveryClient_ZUUL/WGA10015LDITEGG.uswin.ad.swp.com:zuul:8092 - was unable to refresh its cache! status = Cannot execute request on any known server
com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.TransportException: Cannot execute request on any known server
```

Note: Here we are not trygin to register Eureka Clients with our Eureka server. Trying to access other micro services through Zuul gateway and disabling security
using property: security.enabled=false. before migration security.basic.enabled=false. We have tried to disable security as possible using different combinations but still
we are getting the above error.

Can some body tell me what might be issue.

Thanks in advance.